# rails ajax dynamic nested form with many dependencies

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, nested

So, I have 4 selects: user, project, category and **task**, where task belongs to the other three. Only project and category can be blank.

How do you create a dynamic AJAX GET request for task, according to the other 3 values?

Here is my code for reference, but the select is not being dynamically changed.

```
function populateTasks() {
  var project_id = $('.js-project-id').html();
  var category_id = $('.js-category-id').html();
  var user_id = $('.js-user-id').html();

  $.get('http://localhost:3000/tasks').done(function(tasks) {
    if (tasks.length > 0) {
      tasks.forEach(function(task) {
        $('.js-tasks-revision-select').append($("<option/>").val(task._id).html(task.name));
      });
    }
    else {
      $('.js-tasks-revision-select').append($("<option/>").val('').html(''));
    }
  }, true );
}
```

Comment: can you show the route for getting task? what is expected in params and how is it expected? also, what is this current error you are getting from the current implementation?

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm not getting errors. All tasks are being listed and the controller is just a #index render json: Task.all.

Comment: I guess I'm asking the wrong question. can you expatiate on what you wanted done?